# Haskell Map where type of key determines type of value

Tags: haskell

Is there a way to use Data.Map in such a way that the type of value depends upon the type of key? I need to ensure that I am never inserting wrong typed value in the map.

for example:
Let's say I have types `KeyType a` and `ValType a`
then Map should have type similar to

`Map (KeyType a) (ValType a)`

But this obviously does not work because `a` is not bound.

Comment: Sounds like vault https://www.stackage.org/package/vault

Comment: Also consider a [`dependent-map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dependent-map)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a type synonym to bind `a` so that it must be the same for your `KeyType` and `ValType`:

```
type MapFor a = Map (KeyType a) (ValType a)
```

Now you can use `MapFor a` (for some specific `a`) anywhere you would've used `Map (KeyType a) (ValType a)`.

Comment: This will not work for me because for one map, the `a` is fixed. I want the `a` to be different for different keys. I think `dependent-map` will work for me.